# Cohesive zone model finite element implementation

Tags: finite-element

I have a 2D vector $\boldsymbol{u}$ and it's norm is $\lambda$. I have this function:
$$\boldsymbol{T}=\dfrac{\boldsymbol{u}}{\lambda} e^\lambda$$
I need to compute $\boldsymbol{T}$ and it's Jacobean around zero as part of my Newton finite element problem.

The function is poorly defined around 0 and this is causing divergence issues.

This problem is closely associated to the fenics [Cohisve zone model](https://comet-fenics.readthedocs.io/en/latest/demo/cohesive_zone_model/cohesive_zone_model.html) example except that I am looking to use the law above when fracture starts to happen and not prior. At that instant $\boldsymbol{u}$ and $\lambda$ are close to 0.

The literature uses laws like these but as far as I know, it is not explained how one could work around this issue.

Comment: Could you use the function $T_{\varepsilon} = \frac{u}{\sqrt{\lambda^2 + \varepsilon}} e^\lambda$? This sort of regularization is often done when dealing with total variation functionals, which divide by the norm of the gradient.

Comment: Since $T(u)$ is not differentiable at $u=0$, what do you need the derivative for?

Comment: @whpowell96 I will try that
@w

Comment: @whpowell96 this regularization works!! Do you have a quick reference I can read about this a bit more?

Comment: It comes from the fact that $|x| \approx \sqrt{x^2 + \varepsilon}$ but the approximation is differentiable. This citation uses it for TVD regularization and discusses the impact on optimization via Newton's method: 
Chan, Tony F.; Golub, Gene H.; Mulet, Pep_, [**A nonlinear primal-dual method for total variation-based image restoration**](https://doi.org/10.1137/S1064827596299767).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@whpowel has the question answered in the comments. I will re-post it here for the sake of completeness:

Use the function: $$\boldsymbol{T}_{\varepsilon}=\dfrac{\boldsymbol{u}}{\sqrt{
\lambda^2+\varepsilon}} e^{\sqrt{\lambda^2+\varepsilon}}$$